# How do I get a Plymouth sprite to rotate?

Tags: linux, splash-screen

I'm working on a custom Plymouth splash for Kubuntu. I'm attempting to make an image rotate as the system is loading. I have tested it using both reboots and the X11 plugin and have been unsuccessful in both. Here's the .script file:

```
spiral_image = Image("Splash.png");
spiral_sprite = Sprite(spiral_image);

spiral_sprite.SetX(window.GetWidth() /2 - spiral_image.GetWidth() /2);
spiral_sprite.SetY(window.GetHeight() /2 - spiral_image.GetHeight() /2);

fun refresh_callback ()
{
time++;
theta = time / 100;
spiral_sprite.Rotate(theta);
}
Plymouth.SetRefreshFunction (refresh_callback);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to rotate the image, not the sprite:

```
fun refresh_callback () {
  time++;
  theta = time / 100;
  spiral_sprite.SetImage( spiral_image.Rotate(theta) );
}
```

As per [official documentation](https://wiki.freedesktop.org/www/Software/Plymouth/Scripts/), in case anyone finds this question before they manage to find Plymouth documentation.

(Extra notes, slightly off-topic: Documentation says that default text colour is white. Don't count on that too much, it's black.)